# Angular Server Side Rendering (SSR) not loading html for inner / child pages

Tags: angular, angular-routing, server-side-rendering, angular-universal

I'm experiencing an issue with how my angular app loads. For some reason on viewing the application online regardless of the route, the html structure defaults to the base path.

Now assume in my routing I have 2 pages: home `(/)` and events `(/events)`.

When I try to use the facebook open graph scrapper or even just simply `view-source:https://mysite/events` I see the results are that of the homepage `(/)` instead of the `/events`

Even more confusing is that

1. the actual rendered `/events` html file in the `dist` directory has the correct html data but on viewing it online or scrapping as mentioned, it shows the homepage html structure
2. even on loading `https://mysite/events` on the browser - which shows the intended page correctly, but upon inspecting by `ctrl + u`, same issue - html structure belonging to the homepage

Does this have anything to do with how angular loads the app or it's something else? How can I go about ensuring the correct html data is picked up by scrappers or even just by viewing the source?

Just in case the routing info might help, here it is:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: SiteLayoutComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'events',
        children: [
          { path: '', component: EventsComponent},
        ]
      },
      { path: '', component: HomeComponent, pathMatch: 'full'},
    ]
  },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '' }
];
```

Comment: It might be that an error occurs while doing rendering, check server side logs

Comment: @David I build it locally and only publish the `dist` directory which is just html / css / js / assets. While building locally, I get no errors.

Comment: Yes, but after this, when your run SSR, there is a nodejs process running server side, which does the prerendering. If an occurs during pre-rendering, the base index page is returned

Comment: Hi. When testing locally, you cannot just open your `index.html` file or serve the distfiles in a webserver. Are you actually running `npm run start:ssr`?

Comment: @Pieterjan when you run `npm run build:ssr` and `ng run app-name:prerender` it builds actual prerendered html files that you can open on your browser literally without any further commands

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I tested the web application on both my local apache server as well as on another site (which turned out to be using apache) and the routing works fine on both scenarios.

So the issue turned out to be an `nginx` configuration that redirected requests to the root index (then on to the requested page) rather than go straight to the sub directory index.

So if you have a request like `site.com/events` - on `nginx` the request would load the main `index.html` then programmatically load the user's request (`/events`) whereas on `apache` it would go straight to the index found in `/events`

This explains why scrappers like the open graph scrapper or even `ctrl + u` would find meta tag data that's in the main index file rather than the events index file

Comment: So is there any suggestion what we can do on nginx to resolve this issue:

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use EventComponent route, beside HomeComponent.

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: SiteLayoutComponent,
  },
  {
    path: 'events',
    component: EventsComponent,
  },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '' }
];
```

Comment: Is your issue solved? any question?

Comment: Hi, no it did not solve the issue. I think it mainly has to do with the fact that while loading the site even if it's an inner page like `/events/sample-event` - it loads the base path first hence that's what is picked while scrapping or `ctrl + u`